# Using React's immutable helper with Immutable.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I'm working on a flux application and am considering adopting [immutable.js](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js) to maintain state.  I saw that react supplies its own helper for updating immutable objects (http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html), but couldn't tell how it was much different from immutable's own setIn and updateIn methods (i.e, i can already compare objects with === to se if they changes with setIn).  Is there a reason to use the react helper with immutable.js?  Is it just syntactic sugar?

TL;DR is:

```
var map = Immutable.fromJS({bar: 'baz'});
map2 = React.addons.update(map, {
        bar: {$set: 'foo'}
    });
```

different from

```
var map = Immutable.fromJS({bar: 'baz'});
map2 = map.set('bar', 'foo');
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`React.addons.update` does not work with Immutable.js values; it [works with plain JavaScript objects and arrays](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/addons/update.js).

```
var map = { bar: 'baz' };
var map2 = React.addons.update(map, {
  bar: {$set: 'foo'}
});
console.log(map2); // A plain JS object of value `{bar: 'foo'}`
```

The types in Immutable.js are implemented using [special](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_array_mapped_trie) data [structures](http://hypirion.com/musings/understanding-persistent-vector-pt-1) for performance and space benefits; the plain JavaScript objects consumed and produced by React.addons.update, obviously, are not.